# Deselecting mouse event 'mouse:down' after initial event has been rendered

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I am very new to fabric.js, but I am learning quickly.

I have a few items that, when clicked, will fill with the color red.

My problem lies with clicking the image again to reset only that image back to default (black).

Can someone explain how to achieve this?

```
canvas.on('mouse:down', function(e) {
e.target.setFill('red');
e.target.lockMovementX = e.target.lockMovementY = true;
e.target.lockScalingX = e.target.lockScalingY = true;
e.target.lockUniScaling = true;

canvas.deactivateAll().renderAll();
});
```

Please see the [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/fgatlin/hpyrk05w/) for the full example code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the if statement below. It detects the current color and switches it:

```
(function(){
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c4');
canvas.hoverCursor = 'default';

canvas.on('mouse:down', function(e) {

    var color = e.target.fill;
    if(color == '#000')
    {
        e.target.setFill('red');
    } else {
        e.target.setFill('#000');
    }
e.target.lockMovementX = e.target.lockMovementY = true;
e.target.lockScalingX = e.target.lockScalingY = true;
e.target.lockUniScaling = true;


canvas.deactivateAll().renderAll();
  });

canvas.add(new fabric.Circle({ radius: 10, fill: '#000', top: 100, left: 200 }));
canvas.add(new fabric.Circle({ radius: 10, fill: '#000', top: 100, left: 150 }));
canvas.add(new fabric.Circle({ radius: 10, fill: '#000', top: 100, left: 100 }));


})();
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried several times to do an if / else statement, but I forgot to var color each time (duh). Your solution worked very well for me.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/hpyrk05w/3/
it is so simple :
you have to check on mouse down if current fill of object is what?
if current fill is red than fill it with black color and if not, than fill it with red color

```js
(function(){
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c4');
canvas.hoverCursor = 'default';
    
canvas.on('mouse:down', function(e) {
    if(e.target.getFill()=="red")
        e.target.setFill('black');
    else
        e.target.setFill('red');
e.target.lockMovementX = e.target.lockMovementY = true;
e.target.lockScalingX = e.target.lockScalingY = true;
e.target.lockUniScaling = true;

canvas.deactivateAll().renderAll();
  });
   
canvas.add(new fabric.Circle({ radius: 10, fill: '#000', top: 100, left: 200 }));
canvas.add(new fabric.Circle({ radius: 10, fill: '#000', top: 100, left: 150 }));
canvas.add(new fabric.Circle({ radius: 10, fill: '#000', top: 100, left: 100 }));
  
 
})();
```

```css
pre { margin-left: 15px !important }
canvas{border: 1px solid red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://fabricjs.com/lib/fabric.js"></script>
<canvas id="c4" width="450" height="500"></canvas>
```